# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzaaj()Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzg

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am having firebase notification in app and on some devices it is getting crash on receiving of notification.

crash report:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzaaj()Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzg; in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzg; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/my.app-1/base.apk)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzF(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4128)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:229)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1924)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Module dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
```

Project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

I am having all firebase libraries of same version. Please help me out.

Comment: In your app initialization code, are you using [GoogleApiAvailability](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability) to verify that Play Services is installed on the device and is up-to-date?  Maybe the problem is occurring on devices with an old version of Play Services.

Comment: No I'm not checking GoogleApiAvailability , I'll check this out.

Comment: "*on some devices it is getting crash*" -- So this is only for specific devices? Are you seeing a pattern on devices where this occurs (os, model, etc)?